# How can I get the text in a JTable?

Tags: java, jtable

For example I have a Table that I want to get text that's in the first column and store it in an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java Tables often use the TableModel interface for storage.

You can get the a particular value via:

```
myJTable.getModel().getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex);
```

More on that: [Sun's Swing Table Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container cp = frame.getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        final JTable tbl = new JTable(new String[][]{{"c1r1", "c2r1"}, {"c1r2", "c2r2"}}, new String[]{"col 1", "col 2"});

        cp.add(tbl);
        cp.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("click")
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                List<String> colValues = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (int i = 0; i < tbl.getRowCount(); i++)
                    colValues.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(0, i));

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, colValues.toString());
            }
        }));

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through the `JTable`'s [`TableModel`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html), accessible through the `getModel()` method. That has all the information you need.