# How to get text of a jTable's Row or column in java

Tags: java

I Want to getText() of a jTable's row or column but i can't.

```
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tablename.getText(0, 0));
```

but the code snippet above doesn't work, please help.

Comment: `jtable.getModel().getValueAt(row, col)` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) is your friend.

Comment: Maybe this topic could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795936/how-can-i-get-the-text-in-a-jtable

Comment: What is the type of tablename?  Also, can clarify what you mean by "doesn't work"--do you mean it does not compile?

Comment: Thanks Joop Eggen and thanks for everyone